# rviz pre built map from turtlebot3 is only showing a half

Tags: rviz, mapping, ros-noetic, windows

[image: rviz]

I am using WSL ROS noetic, the prebuilt map that is showed by rviz is only a half like on the picture, anyone know why? I tried using the construct workspace also, and it was showing properly. And also the position of the robot is not correspond to that map

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to fix that map, so i can get full map, not half like in the picture